# Python: use asyncio to hit api and output .csv's

Tags: python, pandas, python-asyncio, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to think of how to rewrite some code asynchroniously. I have to download ~7500 datasets from an api and write them to .csv's. Here is a reproducible example (assuming you have a free api key for alpha vantage):

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
api_key = ""

def get_ts(symbol):
    
    ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas')
    data, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=symbol, outputsize='full')
    fname = "./data_dump/{}_data.csv".format(symbol)
    data.to_csv(fname)

symbols = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'TSLA', 'MSFT']

for s in symbols:
    get_ts(s)
```

The people who made the `alpha_vantage` API wrote an article on using it with asyncio [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/which-should-you-use-asynchronous-programming-or-multi-threading-7435ec9adc8e), but I'm not sure if I should make two functions for pulling the data and writing the csv like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999802/use-pythons-asyncio-to-make-an-api-request-and-process-the-result-asynchronousl).

I haven't used asyncio before, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated - just looking to make my download time take less than 3 hours if possible!

**Edit:** The other caveat is I'm helping a researcher with this so we are using Jupyter notebooks - see their caveat for asyncio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518874/how-do-i-run-python-asyncio-code-in-a-jupyter-notebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your function `get_ts`, it might look like this:

```
import multiprocessing

# PROCESSES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
PROCESSES = 4  # number of parallel process
CHUNKS = 6  # one process handle n symbols

# 7.5k symbols
TICKERS = ["BCDA", "WBAI", "NM", "ZKIN", "TNXP", "FLY", "MYSZ", "GASX", "SAVA", "GCE",
           "XNET", "SRAX", "SINO", "LPCN", "XYF", "SNSS", "DRAD", "WLFC", "OILD", "JFIN",
           "TAOP", "PIC", "DIVC", "MKGI", "CCNC", "AEI", "ZCMD", "YVR", "OCG", "IMTE",
           "AZRX", "LIZI", "ORSN", "ASPU", "SHLL", "INOD", "NEXI", "INR", "SLN", "RHE-PA",
           "MAX", "ARRY", "BDGE", "TOTA", "PFMT", "AMRH", "IDN", "OIS", "RMG", "IMV",
           "CHFS", "SUMR", "NRG", "ULBR", "SJI", "HOML", "AMJL", "RUBY", "KBLMU", "ELP"]

# create a list of n sublist
TICKERS = [TICKERS[i:i + CHUNKS] for i in range(0, len(TICKERS), CHUNKS)]


def download_data(pool_id, symbols):
    for symbol in symbols:
        print("[{:02}]: {}".format(pool_id, symbol))
        # do stuff here
        # get_ts(symbol)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(PROCESSES) as pool:
        pool.starmap(download_data, enumerate(TICKERS, start=1))
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66667824/15239951).

> In this example, I split the list of tickers into sublists for each process retrieves data for multiple symbols and limits overhead due to create and destroy processes.

Comment: thanks for this, it looks helpful and less confusing (to me) than using asyncio! i'll try it out and mark as accepted if it works well

Comment: worked great, thanks so much this is awesome!